# Filter 'Search by keyword' not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, search

I am trying to create Search by keyword action in my project. 
Here is the code in the view:

```
<form method="get">
<input type="radio" name="news" value="newest"> Newest First
<input type="radio" name="news" value="keyword"> Keyword Search

<input type="search" name="keyword" id="search" />
<button type="submit" value="Search"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
```

Here is the model:

```
public class News
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the controller where it's not working. The Newest First is giving the right data, but the Keyword first just gives every single object of the list.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult News(String news = null, String text = null)
    {
        if (news == "newest")
        {

            var model =
                from n in _news
                orderby n.Date
                select n;
            return View(model);
        }
        else {

            var model =
                from n in _news
                .Where(n=> text == null || n.Name.Contains(text))
                select n;

            return View(model);        
        }

    }
```

And here are a few of the elements of the News list:

```
static List<News> _news = new List<News>
    {

        new News {

            Id = 1,
            Date = "01/01/2017",
            Name = "blabla",
            Description = "blabla",
            Image = "blabla.jpg",
            Link = "dassda"
        },

        new News {

            Id = 2,
            Date = "vlava",
            Name = "dada",
            Description = "dsadasa",
            Image = "dasdsa.jpg",
            Link = "sdaa"
       };
```

Comment: if text is null it will return all records. and input name does not match parameter.

Comment: `<input type="search" name="text" id="search" />` (not `"keyword"` - it needs to match the name of the parameter in your method)

Comment: I know but I am trying when text is not null and it still returns all records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'search' input has a `name="keyword"` which does not match the name of your parameter. Change one or the other so that they match.

In the view

```
<input type="search" name="keyword" id="search" />
```

or in the controller

```
public ActionResult News(string news, string keyword)
```

and note there is no need to add `= null` (they already are by default)

What you should be doing however is creating a view model with the search properties and the collection

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string News { get; set; } // an enum would be a better choice
    public string Keyword { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<News> NewsList { get; set; }
}
```

and strongly binding to your model using the `HtmlHelper` methods in the view, for example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.KeyWord, new { type="search" })
```

so that when you return the view, the values in your inputs are retained.